# Mathmode in footnote size

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Is there a simple way to put all the text in math-mode in footnotesize instead of inserting the command \begin{footnotesize}...\end{footnotesize} every time?

Comment: Is it the text in mathmode that you want in footnotesize, or the formulæ?

Comment: @Bernard the formulae

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math sizes used for a specific text size are specified using `\DeclareMathSizes` which by default is

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

so at 10pt the active declaration is

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
```

which says to use 10pt math font 7pt script font and 5pt scriptscript, so in the preamble you could  have

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{10pt}{8}{6}{5}
```

as `\footnotesize` is 8pt in the standard classes `10pt` default size option.

Comment: doesn't `\footnotesize` depend on main font size specified in `\documentclass[12 or 10pt]{article}`?

Comment: @C.F.G yes sure I was following on from having used 10pt for the main font size in the example. I'll add a few words to make it clearer/